# Comparing three lists with probabilities and defining an argmax rule

Tags: python, list, numpy-ndarray

Consider a dataset `X` which is a `len(X)`x2 numpy array containing points (each row is an x and a y coordinate) in the plane that have been sampled by 3 different probability distributions. Assume there exists a function `f` that takes as input `X` and produces 3 lists `L1,L2,L3` of length `len(X)` each, with each row corresponding to the probability that a point belongs to distribution 1,2 or 3.

For example we could have:
`L1[0]=0.8, L2[0]=0.1, L3[0]=0.1` which would imply that `X[0]` belongs to distribution 1 since the probability 0.8 is the largest and belongs to `L1`.

**How is it possible to use a "generalized argmax" function such as to create three lists, one for each distribution, that correspond to the points that are found to belong to each distribution?**

In other words, how can I compare each row of the three lists `L1,L2,L3` and assigns each row (that corresponds to each element of the dataset `X`) to a new list using the rule:

If `L1[i]>L2[i] & L1[i]>L2[i]` then `X[i]` belongs/save to to `New_list1`.

If `L1[i]>L2[i] & L1[i]<L3[i]` then `X[i]` belongs/save to `New_list3`

Otherwise `X[i]` belongs/save to `New_list2`.

**NOTE**:
If I had only two arrays `L1,L2` I can do the above as following:

```
arg_max = L1 > L2
New_list1, New_list2 = X[arg_max], X[~arg_max]
```

Of course this won't work with three lists. I need a "trinary" system.

Comment: if X is a 2x2 array, what is len(X) supposed to be?

Comment: Sorry, typo it is a len(X) x 2 array.

Comment: Just to clarify, that dataset name is also the dimension? So dataset 5 would be a 5x2 array?

Comment: It is a dataset called `X`. Its length is `n = len(X)`. Each row is a 1x2 vector containing an x and y coordinate.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand this a bit conceptually. Could you add a short example input and desired outputs, maybe for X=4?

Comment: `X` is a dataset, e.g. `X = np.array([0,0],[1,2],[2,7],[4,6])` where `len(X)=4` here (I have 4 datapoints).

Comment: And given those points, what would the output be?